# Android - Strange Nine Patch Shadow

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, nine-patch

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the following, perhaps a cache setting or something?

Here is my 9 patch:

[image]

Here it is as a PSD screenshot:

[image]

Here it is in Eclipse's Layout Designer:

[image]

And, here it is as captured by DDMS' screenshot tool on a new Galaxy S3:

[image]

See the weird horizontal blur? It's right at the top.

Here is the XML for that bit of layout:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble16"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/temp_comment_3"
        android:textColor="#282828"
        android:textSize="17sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

SDK settings:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Comment: Is `@drawable/bubble16` the image or is it another XML file?

Comment: It could be bilinear filtering.  What happens if you make the resizable part bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's getting scaled up, and the anti-aliasing is causing an in-between gray pixel to bleed into your content area. Same thing is happening to the outer line (it's 2 pixels instead of 1, and the outer area is slightly lighter.)

I'm going to guess you just have this image in `res/drawable`, whereas you need to either:

1. Make larger versions for both `res/drawable-hdpi` (1.5x larger), and `res/drawable-xhdpi` (2x larger). Create these folders if they don't exist -- the S3 is an XHDPI device.
2. Place the 9-patch in `res/drawable-nodpi` which will prevent it from being scaled, but the size won't be consistent between devices. (e.g. it will be smaller on higher density devices)

Comment: Another option - make the "extendable" part bigger, like 20x40 instead of 1x7 px. Antialiasing will be basically non-existent then.